# MySQL - Count logged-in team members

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE members (
  member_id int(1) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  logged_in tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (member_id),
  UNIQUE KEY member_id (member_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO members (member_id, logged_in) VALUES 
  (1, 0),
  (2, 1),
  (3, 1),
  (4, 1),
  (5, 0);

+-----------------------+
| members               |
+-----------+-----------+
| member_id | logged_in |
+-----------+-----------+ 
| 1         | 0         |   
| 2         | 1         |
| 3         | 1         |
| 4         | 1         |
| 5         | 0         |
+-----------+-----------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE team_members (
  team_id int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  member_id int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (team_id,member_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO team_members (team_id, member_id) VALUES 
  (1, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (2, 3),
  (2, 4),
  (3, 5);

+---------------------+
| team_members        |
+---------+-----------+
| team_id | member_id |
+---------+-----------+
| 1       | 1         |
| 1       | 2         |
| 2       | 3         |
| 2       | 4         |
| 3       | 5         |
+---------+-----------+
```

And this is the output I need to achieve:

```
+---------+-----------------------+
| team_id | logged_in_users_count |
+---------+-----------------------+
| 1       | 1                     |
| 2       | 2                     |
| 3       | 0                     |
+---------+-----------------------+
```

I am trying the following sql query but it is not returning the expected output:

```
SELECT 
  tm.team_id,
  (SELECT COUNT(m.logged_in) FROM members m WHERE m.logged_in = 1) AS logged_in_users_count 
FROM
  members m
  INNER JOIN team_members tm ON (m.member_id = tm.member_id)
GROUP BY
  tm.team_id
```

Comment: -1 There just isn't enough information to give you a qualified answer.    how you store information when they login, what you have tried, etc..  show complete information and you'll get better results.

Comment: So you've listed your schema and your desired output, the only missing step is to write the query. There's literally no question in here, so I'm assuming you just want confirmation that this is when you're supposed to write SQL. Yes, you may now write your SQL.

Comment: Sure, I need to refine the sql query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
 team_members.team_id,
 COUNT(members.logged_in)
FROM
 team_members LEFT JOIN members
 ON (team_members.member_id = members.member_id AND members.logged_in = 1)
GROUP BY
  team_members.team_id;
```